# Calling function from another javascript file (Type is not defined)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, aurelia

I'm trying to put the firebase-authentication code in a different .js file and simply import it to my app.js file, but in doing so I'm running into an error I can't solve.

Here's how the auth.js file looks like:

```
export class AuthFirebase
{
  constructor(
        userLoggedIn = false,
        authToken = null,
        user = null,
      ) {
                // This mostly gets called on subsequent page loads to determine
                // what the current status of the user is with "user" being an object
                // return by Firebase with credentials and other info inside of it
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      this.userLoggedIn = user ? true : false;
      this.user = user;
    });
  }
       /* this.auth = AuthService;
    this.authenticated = this.auth.isAuthenticated();
    this.auth.authNotifier.on('authChange', authState => {
      this.authenticated = authState.authenticated;
    });*/

  login(type) {
    let provider;

      // Determine which provider to use depending on provided type
      // which is passed through from app.html
    if (type === 'google') {
      provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    } else if (type === 'facebook') {
      provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
    } else if (type === 'twitter') {
      provider = new firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider();
    }

      // Call the Firebase signin method for our provider
      // then take the successful or failed result and deal with
      // it accordingly.
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then((result: any) => {
          // The token for this session
      this.authToken = result.credential.accessToken;

          // The user object containing information about the current user
      this.user = result.user;

          // Set a class variable to true to state we are logged in
      this.userLoggedIn = true;
      this.router.navigateToRoute('contacts');
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log('Erro no signIn');
      let errorCode = error.code;
      let errorMessage = error.message;
      let email = error.email;
      let credential = error.credential;
    });
  }

  logout() {
      // Self-explanatory signout code
    firebase.auth().signOut().then(() => {
      this.userLoggedIn = false;
      this.router.navigateToRoute('inicio');
    }).catch(error => {
      throw new Error(error);
    });
  }
}
```

And here's how I'm importing it in the app.js file:

```
import { inject } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { Redirect } from 'aurelia-router';
import {AuthFirebase} from './common/auth';

function findDefaultRoute(router) {
  return router.navigation[0].relativeHref;
}

@inject(AuthFirebase)
export class App {

  constructor(authfirebase) {
    this.authfirebase = authfirebase;
  }

  login() {
    this.authfirebase.login(type);
  }

  logout() {
    this.authfirebase.logout();
  }
//...
```

I figured logout() just needs to be called when needed but I need to add something to login(), because when I invoke it I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: type is not defined
    at App.login (app.js:25)
    at CallScope.evaluate (vendor-bundle.js:23250)
    at Listener.callSource (vendor-bundle.js:26902)
    at Listener.handleEvent (vendor-bundle.js:26911)
    at HTMLDocument.handleDelegatedEvent (vendor-bundle.js:24981)
```

If anyone could help me out I'd appreciate it, thanks.

**UPDATE**

auth.js code

```
import { inject } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { ContactGateway } from '../contacts/services/gateway';
import { Router } from 'aurelia-router';

@inject(Router, ContactGateway)
export class AuthFirebase
{
  constructor(userLoggedIn = false, authToken = null, user = null, router, contactGateway) {
    this.router = router;
    this.contactGateway = contactGateway;
                // This mostly gets called on subsequent page loads to determine
                // what the current status of the user is with "user" being an object
                // return by Firebase with credentials and other info inside of it
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      this.userLoggedIn = user ? true : false;
      this.user = user;
    });
  }
       /* this.auth = AuthService;
    this.authenticated = this.auth.isAuthenticated();
    this.auth.authNotifier.on('authChange', authState => {
      this.authenticated = authState.authenticated;
    });*/

  login(type) {
    let provider;

      // Determine which provider to use depending on provided type
      // which is passed through from app.html
    if (type === 'google') {
      provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    } else if (type === 'facebook') {
      provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
    } else if (type === 'twitter') {
      provider = new firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider();
    }

      // Call the Firebase signin method for our provider
      // then take the successful or failed result and deal with
      // it accordingly.
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then((result: any) => {
          // The token for this session
      this.authToken = result.credential.accessToken;
          // The user object containing information about the current user
      this.user = result.user;

          // Set a class variable to true to state we are logged in
      this.userLoggedIn = true;
      console.log('antes do navigate');
      this.router.navigateToRoute('contacts');
      console.log('depois do navigate');
    }).catch(error => {
      let errorCode = error.code;
      let errorMessage = error.message;
      let email = error.email;
      let credential = error.credential;
      console.log('Erro no signIn - ' + errorMessage);
    });
  }

  logout() {
      // Self-explanatory signout code
    firebase.auth().signOut().then(() => {
      this.userLoggedIn = false;
      this.router.navigateToRoute('inicio');
    }).catch(error => {
      throw new Error(error);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: when you call login from your class in your app (`this.authfirebase.login(type);`), where did you define the `type` variable? isn't it missing, or you simplified for the exemple?

Comment: login(type) {
    this.authfirebase.login(type);
  }

Comment: @AlexanderPoshtaruk that seemed to fix the issue, now though on my login() on the auth.js file, I get an error related to the navigateToRoute (Cannot read property 'navigateToRoute' of undefined), I've imported Router from 'aurelia-router' on the auth.js file and injected it, but that doesn't seem to fix the issue, anything I might be missing?

Comment: Need a code to look at

Comment: @AlexanderPoshtaruk I've updated the main post with the code.

Comment: Can you console.log this.router in constructor whether it is defined?

Comment: And if yes - then we should take a look on 'this' in callback function of firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(

Comment: @AlexanderPoshtaruk well thought, doing console.log(router) on the constructor returns undefined, there's the problem, so what am I doing wrong when taking it in the constructor then?

Comment: I am not familiar with Aurelia framework, but just assumption: in you have 5 params in constructor, shouln't you provide 5 appropriate values in @inject decorator?

Comment: I believe you only need to inject what you import, so the other 3 values aren't needed inside the inject, though I figured messing around on the constructor that if I just leave the Router and contactGateway, they're both defined, so it's either the order they are defined or how they're called on the constructor (the other 3 values).

Comment: If I remove the function inside the constructor, it works, but I need the function inside it, not sure how to go about this.